# Get all unique combinations of elements from list in Python

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I looked up many related questions, but no one actually answers me how to receive ALL combinations of the elemets in a list. For example, with this input list

```
input_list = ["apple", "orange", "carrot"]
```

I would like to have this list:

```
output_list = [ ["apple"], ["orange"], ["carrot"], ["apple", "orange"],  ["apple", "carrot"], ["orange", "carrot"], ["apple", "orange", "carrot"]]
```

i.e. I also want to have the single entries included, how can I do this?

Comment: You're looking for `itertools.combinations` with a list comprehension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a oneliner answer is:

```
[list(j) for i in range(len(input_list )) for j in itertools.combinations(input_list , i+1)]
```

the first loop (`i`) goes over all different combinations and creates the combination object, then the second loop (`j`) goes over every element of the combination and makes a list of it then appends it to the original list. The output is as you want, without changing anything.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the [`powerset` itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

---

```
>>> input_list = ["apple", "orange", "carrot"]
>>> print(list(map(list, powerset(input_list)))[1:])
[['apple'], ['orange'], ['carrot'],['apple', 'orange'], ['apple', 'carrot'], ['orange', 'carrot'], ['apple', 'orange', 'carrot']]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is almost what you're looking for, minus some formatting:

```
from itertools import combinations
input_list = ["apple", "orange", "carrot"]
combis = [[i for i in combinations(input_list, 1)], [i for i in combinations(input_list, 2)], [i for i in combinations(input_list, 3)]]
```

Output:

```
 [[('apple',), ('orange',), ('carrot',)],
 [('apple', 'orange'), ('apple', 'carrot'), ('orange', 'carrot')],
 [('apple', 'orange', 'carrot')]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools` documentation provides a set of [useful recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) for things easily implemented using the module; among them is a powerset generator:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Given your list of strings, you'll get a list of *tuples*.

```
>>> list(powerset(input_list))
[(), ('apple',), ('orange',), ('carrot',), ('apple', 'orange'), ('apple', 'carrot'), ('orange', 'carrot'), ('apple', 'orange', 'carrot')]
```

The empty tuple is easily filtered, and the tuples can be converted to lists if necessary.

```
>>> list(list(x) for x in powerset(input_list) if x != ())
[['apple'], ['orange'], ['carrot'], ['apple', 'orange'], ['apple', 'carrot'], ['orange', 'carrot'], ['apple', 'orange', 'carrot']]
```